# Memorably stupid line from very old movie: "Any quantum mechanic could fix that."

Tags: story-identification, movie, b-movies

Long ago (perhaps 1960s) I saw one of the worst science fiction movies ever made.  I remember nothing about it except it was awful, and contained the following line (which I may not remember 100% correctly):

> Any quantum mechanic could fix that.

That's it. Does anyone know anything about this turkey?

Comment: If that one line is all you can remember (perhaps incorrectly) from it, **how do you know it was a science fiction movie?** Did it have any "science-fictional elements" (space aliens, ray guns, and like that) that you can recall (and neglected to tell us about)? If not, your question would seem to be off topic here.

Comment: One of the worst science fiction movies ever made? Have you seen any of the last ten Hollywood blockbusters?

Comment: I don't approve but it seems to be the custom here to close identification requests as "off topic" if the asker merely states that the work was science fiction or fantasy but can't provide details to justify that diagnosis.

Comment: @user14111 if the OP states a work is SFF-nal but no details state as such we give the question the benefit of the doubt and leave it open.  See [meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12176/58193).

Comment: I'm thinking it might be from "Forbidden Planet" (1956) - actually a sci-fi classic. It was rather well made and very forward-looking for its time, even thought it doesn't look it by today's standards; a very cerebral story based off Shakespeare's "The Tempest" and very much apparent inspiration for Gene Roddenberry's Star Trek. Although a benchmark for sci-fi storytelling, it did have a few cheesy moments. I believe the line you quoted was spoken by "Quinn" (Richard Anderson) in a two-shot with "Commander Adams" (Leslie Nielsen) as they stand over a bench laden with strange equipment.

Comment: @Anthony X, that's exactly what I thought, and why I asked to reopen. Posted it as an answer, as I think it's important to educate OP on classic sf

Comment: @WolfieSmith Agreed. Despite any flaws you might see, its core sci-fi theme of technology (the Krell machine) gone awry is still as relevant today as ever (consider Black Mirror).

Comment: When Star Trek came, I deliberately ignored its many bizarre moments, of which raising "one to the tenth power" was perhaps the worst.   Also the  sequence when the computer tried so hard to divide by zero.  I decided to just enjoy Star Trek as the trailblazer it was, even though it fell short of  good written SF.    Whether Forbidden Planet was the origin of the remark I noted, I don't remember, obviously!   But, as a seasoned SF reader (since the age of 12), I found it ludicrous at the time,  possibly because I was too serious being a physics major.

Comment: @ab2 movie science techspeak in the 50s & 60s was like movie computer techspeak in the 80s, movie internet techspeak in the early naughties, movie AI techspeak around now, and probably movie hyperjump techspeak 20 years from now.

Comment: Why is that line memorably stupid?  If in that fictional future, there are people trained to work with devices based on the principles of quantum mechanics, would it be implausible that they came to be known as "quantum mechanics?

Comment: In English language there are two different meanings of mechanics. It can be people ("mechanici" in Dutch) and is can be mechanics ("mechanica" in Dutch). Or mechanicien and mechanique in French. English language sucks in this respect, though context can tell. Just as in this case.

Comment: @jamesqf Possibly.  However the one good example of such an effect I can come up on the spur of the moment went in the opposite direction.  Before computers, the men (and possibly a woman or two) who did calculations were called computers.  A computer -- a man whose job description was computer -- calculated the height of Everest.  So I stand by my judgment about quantum mechanic, although quantum scientist, like computer scientist, is another story.

Comment: @ab2 "*the men (and possibly a woman or two)*" - actually, for about a century, especially during the two world wars and also [at Harvard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_Computers), those [computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_(occupation)) were mostly women.

Comment: Considering quantum means in a discrete unit, I'd imagine most mechanics are quantum; maybe not if they've had a leg amputated or something...

Comment: @Rand al'Thor  The height of Everest was announced in 1856 by the English -- before the period you are talking about.  And far away from progressive (ahem) Harvard.  If you know of any Englishwoman besides Ada Lovelace working as or with computers at that time, I'd really like to hear about it.

Comment: @ab2 - Mary Edwards (1750-1815) worked as a human computer for the British Nautical Almanac, and she wasn't the only one.

Comment: @ab2 after her death her daughter Eliza took over for another 15 years.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This sounds very much like a quote from what was one of the seminal sf works of its time, and one of my personal favourites, if a little cheesy by today's standards.

The movie I'm thinking of is [Forbidden Planet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbidden_Planet), from 1956.

The actual quote from the movie is:

> I'll bet any quantum mechanic in the service would give the rest of his life to fool around with this gadget.

Comment: IIRC the gadget in question is a core component of the ship's FTL drive. Due to the circumstances found on the planet, the commander needs to consult up the leadership chain for new orders; the only way to send an FTL message is to extract and repurpose a core component of the FTL drive, temporarily stranding them on the planet. I believe the quoted line comes up as the chief works on the task.

Comment: The other bad science dialog I remember from that movie was something along the lines of "a billion electron volts!" used as if that was a lot of energy.

Comment: I wanted to upvote this answer but couldn't after reading "by today's standards".

Comment: @user14111 I did think about removing that comment, but I decided to stand by it. While most modern sci-fi certainly suffers from a glut of lazy, derivative writing, it has got less 'cheesy' in general, I feel. Don't get me wrong, I love me some good cheese

Comment: In my youth *Forbidden Planet* was considered a leading contender for "best science fiction movie ever made". I don't know about that, but if it had been made in the last 20 years it would be a shoo-in for "best science fiction movie of the last 20 years". But that is faint praise; you could say the same about *The Attack of the 50 Foot Woman* or *Slave Girls from Beyond Infinity*.

Comment: @user14111 Sounds like you're caught up in nostalgia TBH.

Comment: @user14111 **it is** one of the best SF movies ever made, because #1 a very pretty girl in a very short skirt, #2 a music score which defined the genre, and #3 a story about what it means to be human.

Comment: @RonJohn I wouldn't dare dispute the point about "pretty girl in a short skirt", but seriously, I think what made "Forbidden Planet" one of the best sci-fi movies ever made was the "what if" questions built into the story... What if we could command almost unlimited power by mere thought? Could anyone not be corrupted by near absolute power? Could we maintain control over a power directed by thought alone? There is also the matter of a robot appearing in a story as a reliable and trustworthy servant - loyal, respectful of life, and never goes on a murderous rampage.

Comment: @RonJohn #4 It was a major inspiration to Gene Roddenberry.  If the story feels a lot like a TOS episode, there's a reason for that!